# What word do I use for the work universities are required to do?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

When I want to talk in general terms about the work that a university is required to do (basically creating and teaching courses and programmes), what word do I use? Do I talk about the university's *commission*? Or their *assignment*? Or their *task*? Or what?

I need it in the following sentence:

> *Due to the erratic nature of our ***[requested word]***, it is difficult to plan ahead.*

At first, I was thinking about simply using *work* here, but that doesn't work because it's not the work as such that is erratic, but rather the way we are requested to first come up with lots of new courses, then slow down, then cater for some new area of interest and so on. That is, it's the commision (if, indeed, that is the right word to use) that is erratic, not the work as such. Oh, I do hope someone understands what I'm on about here...

Comment: The [**curriculum**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/curriculum)?

Comment: @WeatherVane Mm, I see I've failed to explain what I'm after... A university is asked/commissioned/demanded (or whatever it may be called) by the government to do what they do, right? So it has a commission (or whatever it may be called) from the government, right? A curriculum results from this commission (or whatever it may be called). Do you see what I mean? You wouldn't say that the university's curriculum is to create courses and programmes, right?

Comment: No, I don't think that 'western' universites work that way. They are independent, but if they are controlled by government they might be given a [**brief**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brief) (noun) *A set of instructions given to a person about a job or task.*

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, they do in my country... But what about ordinary schools then? Surely they work at the request of the government in most countries (if they are state schools)? Would you really say that they have a brief from the government? A brief to me is something far less formal, something that is not regulated in laws etc?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't mean to be rude – I'm immensely grateful that you're taking the time to answer all my weird questions...

Comment: Yes, we have independent schools and state schools, whose curriculum is set by the government. So their curriculum is constantly changing, or is erratic (and it is!)

Comment: @WeatherVane Right! So what would you call that then? Would you say "Schools' commission is to educate children" or what word would you use instead of commission, to indicate the 'task' given by the government?

Comment: Please see [**The national curriculum**](https://www.gov.uk/national-curriculum) as ordained by the UK government. The schools' **job** or **task** is to educate  children, but your sentence would work well as "Due to the erratic nature of our curriculum, it is difficult to plan ahead."

Comment: @WeatherVane Haha, now I feel really stupid... how does this link give me the word I'm looking for? (Again: I don't mean to be rude!)

Comment: Please see edited comment. Using 'curriculum' is more specific than 'task', which could be anything, from managing difficult students to allocating the financial budget. The curriculum is what they are told to teach.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you! So I can't use "commission" in this context? Thing is, the various curricula are something we (as a university) put together ourselves, on the basis of our "commission" to provide higher education, so "curriculum" doesn't work in my specific context... But you're saying "task" would work here? For something that is regulated in the law?

Comment: You put together **courses** and **programs** to meet the **curriculum**. I am *not* saying 'task' will work: I said it is too broad.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes – sorry; I hadn't seen that addition to the comment when I wrote that... But I can't use "commission" then?

Comment: I would say it is more of an instruction than a commission.

Comment: @WeatherVane and yes, at schools they design courses etc to meet the curriculum; at the university we make up our own curricula. Just a parenthesis :)

Comment: Sorry, you said that you are told what to teach, and now you say the opposite.

Comment: @WeatherVane Huh? Did I? What I meant was that we're told to increase or decrease production; to cater for new popular demands and so on. We're not told what to teach. I'm sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @WeatherVane Anyway, I think I'll just have to accept that English seems to lack the word I'm looking for... Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Check a dictionary for "mission". It might fit.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you! I've consulted all the dictionaries I can think of now, but I'm still unsure whether I can use this word in this context? Would you say that you get a misson from a government to do something? And could I really say "Due to the erratic nature of our mission"?

Comment: Maybe the word "erratic", which sounds disorderly, isn't the best choice. Maybe it's a "shifting" or "changeable", or "fluid" mission. "Due to the fluid nature or our mission..." A commission comes entirely from outside, a mission could be self-assigned though influenced from outside. Many organizations have a "mission statement" defining what they are trying to do.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes, exactly! "Mission" is more of a self-assigned task. What I'm after is the "task" that the government require us to do; not necessarily what we ourselves set out to do. See what I mean? For instance, our *mission* is to provide excellent education for life-long learning (that's what *we* set out to do), whereas the "task" set up by the government is something else.  As for the use of "erratic" I see what you mean, but the whole point is to mark it as something negative – "shifting", "changeable" and "fluid" are all neutral (or even slightly positive), aren't they?

Comment: I'd say they are neutral. Even if it's externally imposed at first, mission may fit. Another possibility for an externally imposed mission is "mandate".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes!! I think mandate might work! I'll have to rephrase a bit, but yes – I think this is the word I was looking for! Thank you so much!